# VueJS + VUEX + VueRouter: Making A Component Unloadable?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I want to secure a certain route / component.

It should not be loadable.

How do I secure a route / component in VueJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use aliasing and redirecting: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html

Or use Navigation Guards so you can display things if someone tries to get there: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html